# Rails 6 deployment setup with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, sudo

I am trying to deploy my Ruby On Rails 6 Application to a VPS with Ubuntu 20.04.

I run `cap production setup` and end up with this error :

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deployer@the_IP_address: sudo exit status: 1
sudo stdout: Nothing written
sudo stderr: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
```

This might also give a clue :

```
00:00 rbenv:validate
      rbenv: rbenv_ruby is not set; ruby version will be defined by the remote hosts via rbenv
00:00 nginx:setup
      Uploading /tmp/mrb-va_production 100.0%
      01 sudo mv /tmp/mrb-va_production /etc/nginx/sites-available
      01 sudo
      01 :
      01 a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
      01
```

Do you have an idea what to do in this case ?

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#authorisation

Comment: @MibraDev I had done this, but miswritten the line. I corrected it and deployment works fine now. Thanks

Comment: @user13246558 so how did you fix your config?